# Azure Mobile Services Custom API Parameters in Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a Custom API set up in Azure Mobile Services (JS):

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    var tables = request.service.tables;
    var accounts = tables.getTable('Account');
    var item = {
        id: request.body.members.id
    }

    accounts.where(function (item) {
        return this.id == item.id;
    }, item).read({
    success: function (results) {
        if (results.length === 0) {
                response.send(200, { Status: "FAIL", Error: "Something went wrong." });
         }
         else
         {
        var account = results[0];
        response.send(200, {
           id: account.id,
           name: account.name,
           email: account.email
        });
}
        }
    });
};
```

I'm calling it from Android with:

```
List<Pair<String, String> > lp = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String> >();
            lp.add(new Pair("id", userId));

            mClient.invokeApi("custAPI", "POST", lp, whoami.class, new ApiOperationCallback<custAPI>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(custAPI result,
                                        Exception error, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        Log.w("TEST", result.name.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

The Custom API is being called but the parameters do not seem to be being passed - `request.body.members.id` does not exist.

How do I properly pass parameters into a Custom API on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a custom class for this. For example you want to send member info you can create a class like following:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Member {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int ID;
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String Name;
}
```

Now call the invokeApi Method and pass in Member object.

```
Member member = new Member();
member.ID = 1;
member.Name = "Someone";
mClient.invokeApi("custAPI", "POST", member, Member.class, new ApiOperationCallback<custAPI>()
```

And inside your custom API you will have access to your object and you can access using request.body.id for the id and request.body.name for the name inside the member object.

Comment: Hey...thanks for sharing it with us ... I have a problem can u help....Although I know various things in azure like retrieving and inserting data to non-sql table but still I am new to azure , want some tutorial on how to write and use API .plss provide me some link

Comment: one more question ...how can i retrieve and use a single value in android . I am taking about single value not the whole list as specified in azure tutorial.